# Objective-C equivalent of Java function

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays

How could I write an Objective-C equivalent of this Java code?

```
public static @Nullable byte[] getUnknownData(Sample s){
    int length = s.data.length-index;
    byte data[] = new byte[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        data[i]=s.data[UNKNOWN_STATUS_INDEX+i].byteValue();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Objective-C code:

```
- (NSData *)getUnknownData:(Sample s) {
    int length = s.data.count-index;
    NSData * data = [NSData alloc]init;
    . . . ????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSMutableData` which is a modifiable subclass of `NSData`:

```
-(NSData *)getUnknownData:(Sample s){
   int length = s.data.count-index;
   NSMutableData *theData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:length];

   theData.length = length;
   char *theBytes = (char *)theData.mutableBytes;
   for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
       theBytes[i] = (char)[s.data[UNKNOWN_STATUS_INDEX + i] intValue]
   }
   return [theData copy];
}
```

After reserving the needed amount of bytes you have to convert each value from the array into the data object.

Comment: I've this error: Property 'bytes' not found on object of type 'NSArray<NSNumber *> *'

Comment: *After reserving the needed amount of bytes* Only as side note: The capacity is not the total amount of bytes that can be hold by the instance, but simply a hint.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I meant `theData.length = length;` This will ensure that the byte buffer has a size from at least `length` bytes, and the data object must not make it smaller.